# Properties file backslash and semicolon

Tags: java, properties

I have a Java class to write/append into existing properties file. After appending, it's replacing all single backslash with double backslash and it places single backslash before every semicolon.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
  String systemPath=request.getParameter("SYSTEMPATH");
  String deployPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/DB.properties");
  InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/DB.properties");
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.load(stream);
  prop.setProperty("Workspace", systemPath);
  File file = new File(deployPath);
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
  prop.store(fileOut, "sample properties");
  fileOut.close();
}
```

Before appending:

> Url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.22:1521/
>
> Workspace=D:\RACHEL\SW\Antivirus

after appending:

> Url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.22:1521/
>
> Workspace=D:\\RACHEL\\SW\\Antivirus

How to remove these extra backslashes?

Answer (score 3):

The properties file *should* have the extra backslashes to start with. In particular, without them you could end up with the wrong data, e.g. if you have `d:\foo\new` that wouldn't mean what you expect it to.

The backslashes escape characters which are sensitive in properties files, basically. The colons are unnecessary (as they're not in the key) but they don't do any harm either. The doubling of backslashes for text is entirely beneficial.

This is documented in the `Properties` documentation - in particular, look at the [`store()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) method that you're calling.

Comment: any solution?? but when i read those values from properties file, it will have extra backslashes rite?

Comment: @BobbyRachel: No, it won't. They're just correct escaping - when you use `Properties.load()`, they will be unescaped, effectively. The problem is that it *didn't* have the extra backslashes to start with - you need to fix whatever was creating the original properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Properties file has [their own format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties). *Colon* and *backslashes* are special characters in properties file. So, they have to be escaped. Also take a look at [Properties.`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) documentation.

If you are using `Properties` class to *write* and *read* the file, there won't be any problem. But, if you write the properties file using `Property` class, and read using some other method, then you would have to handle the escapes manually.

Comment: Colons and backslashes don't *have* to be escaped in values... although backslashes followed by valid escape sequences do.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the key and its value and check and it will not vary but in properties file 
It seems to look with extra slashes

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, as I was on stackoverflow on another issue. I remember had this code!
I hope it helps, at least it is java, but it does escaping an issue in  Properties file backslash and semicolon pitfall.

```
  // load to store prop
  @SuppressWarnings ( "resource" )
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( configFile );
  pw.println( "#" + LocalDateTime.now() );
  pw.println( "hibernate.connection.username=" +  prop.getProperty( "hibernate.connection.username" ) );
  pw.println( "hibernate.connection.password=" + prop.getProperty( "hibernate.connection.password" ) );
  pw.println( "hibernate.connection.url=" + prop.getProperty( "hibernate.connection.url" ) );
  pw.close();
```