# Type full width colon (:) to setProperty in Java

Tags: java, escaping

I'm trying to set my database property, so in the future users could change it if they want to change the route of the database. The problem is when I try to set something with full width colon, which always add a backslash escape character .

I've tried normal and double escape, but it doesn't work.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SetProps {

public static void SetDefaultProps(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;

try {

    output = new FileOutputStream("./build/classes/configuracion.properties");

    // Set the database property
    prop.setProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.192:3306/ordenestaller");


// Save Properties
    prop.store(output, null);

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SetDefaultProps();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape anything in the mySQL URL, a colon is a regular character

Comment: Function setProperty always add to : the backslash /:

Comment: Ist is not the 'setProperty` - Method. It is the `store` Method that will add the //

Comment: you give me the point! @Jens

Comment: Got the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990740/properties-file-backslash-and-semicolon

There is no problem with that backslash, properties file consider full width colon as a special character so it's needed.
Also, properties.load() returns the information without that backslashes.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding the db url in the java code is not a good coding practice.
I would recommend you to put those urls in a properties files and read them as and when required using a ResouceBundle.

you can have "information.properties" file somewhere in your classpath and the contents of that file can be

```
dbURL:jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.192:3306/ordenestaller
```

and now in your code you can get this using a ResourceBundle

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("information");
String dbURL= bundle.getString("dbURL");
```

This will have an added advantage that you will not need to recompile your java class again if DB URl is changed.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to type the full width colon because I'm setting also directory path and the C:/Documents and Settings.... is adding the backlash again C\:/