# JBOSS-EAP7 what is an EJB Receiver and how do I make my standalone client app provide one?

Tags: jakarta-ee, client, ejb-3.0, jboss-eap-7

This is a continuation of the [pathetic saga I presented earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574751/standalone-jboss-ejb-client-application-how-to-get-jndi-connection-distinct).

The basic problem here is to port an ancient EJB from Web Logic to JBoss.  This bean has methods that must be invoked from a standalone client application running on another server.

I never solved that but eventually made some progress by avoiding the "ejb:" JNDI naming strategy.

Following [this article](https://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/26/jboss-eap-wildfly-three-ways-to-invoke-remote-ejbs/), which outlines 3 strategies I tried the second one, "2. Remote Naming Project".  The article describes this as having some disadvantages but may be more appropriate to my situation, which performs bean initialization in the ejbCreate method, called from the home interface.  Following this strategy, I now initialize my context as follows before looking up the bean:

```
        public InitialContext createInitialContext() throws NamingException {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, myUrl);
            prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, myUserName);
            prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, myPassword);
            prop.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

            return new InitialContext(prop);            
        }
```

In any event my code no longer fails in instantiating the bean, where it failed with the strategy I was using, but it does fail when methods on the bean are invoked - with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000027: No EJBReceiver available for node name myServerName
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireNodeEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:904) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireNodeEJBReceiverContext(EJBClientContext.java:945) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:68) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146) ~[ttjd.jar:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.iAmAlive(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
...
```

So the question is "what is an EJBReceiver" and what must I do in setting up my client to make it one?  Are there some other parameters I need to put in the context?

**UPDATE:** Adding the following to `createInitialContext()` didn't help:

```
prop.put("jboss.naming.client.endpoint.name", nameOfEjbServer);
```

Comment: I've answered your original question

Comment: Thanks, I've commented on your answer on the original question, but this is the more pressing question as I can't even initialize my client the other way, whereas with the scheme here, I can initialize the client but fail when invoking methods.